# Scoring a hypothetical taxi route based on the timelines of arrival at the destination

Tags: probability, bayesian, distributions

I am currently tackling my first statistics problem, never having studied statistics before, and I could use some help determining if the concepts I've studied so far apply to my problem, and if so, how to apply them.

My problem can be summarized as:

> Given a *target arrive by time* from a passenger, and a *planned arrive by time* from a potential route, return a *score* for the route derived from the the *delta* between the *planned arrive by time* and the *target arrive by time*.

I have no actual observations going into the problem, but I have formed some subjective opinions after studying the problem space:

- Arriving perfectly on time should return a perfect score (e.g. `1`)
- Arriving a few minutes early should return a less-than-perfect score (e.g. `0.85`)
- Arriving a few minutes late should return an lower score than arriving early by the same time (e.g. `0.65` for the same absolute difference in the previous example)
- The score should continue to go down as the delta moves away from 0 (perfectly on time) to infinity and -infinity

It seems like the first step is to come up with a some kind of probability distribution that represents the subjective opinions above. Armed with that, it seems like I could answer questions like: "what is the average score for a given delta?" and "what is the probability that a given route will result in a score above some minimum threshold?".

The next step is to re-enforce the model with data from a simple 5-star rating system where passengers are asked to give a 1 to 5 star rating of their ride's timeliness. The 1-5 scale would be scaled to the same 0-1 scale used above. For this, it seems like I could use Bayesian Inference. I would use random samples from the distribution created above as my prior, then apply data from actual rides to achieve a more informed posterior distribution to answer the same questions as above.

Providing that method works, it seems like you could use another round of Bayesian Inference to apply specific rider data to the previous distribution. The model derived from all users and the subjective prior would serve as the new prior, and the observations would be specific to the user in question. In this way you would develop a personal profile of each user to account for varying tolerances to being early or late.

My first question is, am I heading in the right direction to solve my problem? If so, is my understanding and application of probability distributions and bayesian inference correct? Providing I'm not totally misunderstanding things, what should be my next steps to solving the problem?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @gung It's not. My apologies if the quoted problem summary made it seem like it – I wrote that.